# Only keep values from a long xml string

Tags: ruby, xml

Hello I have this long xml string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Would it be possible to remove everything (including all xmlns attributes) but the parts between `<soap:body></soap:body>` like this

```
<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>
    <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>
</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>
```

If new lines or identation is not possible that would be ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri’s [`xpath`](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) comes to the rescue:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Enve....'
xxml = Nokogiri::XML.parse xml
xxml.xpath('//soap:Body/*').to_s
#⇒ "<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse ..."
```

Comment: ~doc = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>')~    ~xml_str = doc.remove_namespaces!.xpath('//Body/*').to_s~  this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`doc = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>')
xml_str = doc.remove_namespaces!.xpath('//Body/*').to_s`

this brings the desired result

```
<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>
  <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>
</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>
```